# Jenkins could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab, jenkins, devops

Jenkins не имеет прав для стягивания изменений с репозитория. В `Deploy keys` репозитория добавлен публичный ключ моего текущего пользователя на сервере `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Машина Win 2012 R2, Jenkins 2.6.

Добавлял Credentials двумя способами.

Первый - использовал настройку `Username with password` и добавил логин/пасс пользователя с заведомо достаточными правами.

```
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists
```

Второй - использовал настройку `SSH Username with private key` + `From the Jenkins master ~/.ssh`, куда скопировал `~/.ssh`

```
 stderr: Load key "C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\ssh5189845575748942561.key": invalid format 
 Permission denied (publickey). 
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Где допускаю ошибку? И как мне разобраться с данными для подключения дженкинса к гитлабу?

Comment: Проверьте, что репозиторий вообще пингуется с дженкинса.

Comment: `Load key "...": invalid format ` намекает на то, что ключ невалидный. Вы ему точно нужный `id_rsa` дали?

Comment: Самое простое — открыть репозиторий для публичного доступа, а в дженкинсе его клонировать по https. Тогда авторизация вовсе не нужна.

Comment: @NickVolynkin репозиторий приватный, тут не поменяешь. Ключ валидный для моего пользователя, с ним же я могу выполнять любые действия с репозиторием. Увидел в настройках дженкинса его корневой каталог и скопировал свой .ssh/ туда. Возможно, вы правы и дженкинс не понимает этот формат ключей. Тогда мне не понятно, какие ключи он вообще использует.

Comment: @NickVolynkin не понял сообщение `репозиторий вообще пингуется с дженкинса`. Через веб-интерфейс как-то или через консоль со сменой пользователя на jenkins (через моего текущего пользователя репозиторий доступен)? к сожалению, в Win не вижу такого пользователя

Comment: Я имел в виду, что хост с репозиторием вообще доступен с хоста дженкинса. Сообщение «...and the repository exists» появляется в том числе когда репозиторий просто недоступен. Например, если вы отключите комп от сети и попробуете `git fetch` где-нибудь, то будет именно это сообщение.

Comment: Попробуйте зайти на машинку с дженкинсом и оттуда `ssh -T git@repo.tld`

Comment: @NickVolynkin команды git'а для текущего пользователя проходят все (fetch, pull, push). После выполнения команды `ssh -T git@git.mysite.ru/myrepo.git` получаю сообщение `Name or service not known`. Сервер с гитлабом и сервер разработки находятся в одной подсети

Comment: Вы пробовали вариант со вставкой ключа private-key (именно private, не public) в Jenkins credential в поле `Enter Directly`?